# Difficulty in understanding converse part of proof of a propostion in Andrew Browder's Mathematical Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

> Proposition: Let $\mu$ be finitely additive set function, defined on the algebra $\mathscr A$. Then $\mu$ is countably additive if and only if its has following property: if $A_n \in \mathscr A$ and $A_n \subset A_{n+1}$ for each positive integer $n$, and if $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \in \mathscr A$, then $\mu(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n)= \lim_{n\to \infty} \mu(A_n)$.

To prove converse, that is to prove that $\mu$ is countably additive the proof given is as below:

> Suppose that $\mu$ is finitely additive, and has the given property(called as "continuity from below" property). If $A_n$ is a sequence of pairwise disjoint sets in $\mathscr A$, and we put $B_n=\cup_{k=1}^{n}A_k$, then $B_n \subset B_{n+1}$ for every $n$, so $\mu(B_n) \to \mu(B)$, where $B=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$. But since $\mu$ is finitely additive, $\mu(B_n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \mu(A_k)$, so $\mu(B_n) \to \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_k)$. Thus, $\mu$ is countably additive.

My difficulties:

- Where was the "Continuity from below" property used?
- Since we are working on an algebra i.e. $\mathscr A$, how come $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \in \mathscr A$?(This difficulty came to me because $\mu(B)$ is mentioned in the proof but for that to happen, $B$ must belong to $\mathscr A$. Also $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n \in \mathscr A$ is one of the statements in the hypothesis of the "continuity from below" property so $B\in \mathscr A$ should happen in order to get the result.)

I am seeking for a different approach to this converse part too.

Comment: You don't need a $\sigma$-algebra. It's part of the hypothesis, "and if $\bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty A_n \in \mathscr{A}$", that you only look at cases where the union of a countable family $\{ A_n\} \subset\mathscr{A}$ happens to be a member of $\mathscr{A}$. That can happen - for some families $\{ A_n\}$ - if $\mathscr{A}$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra. If it is a $\sigma$-algebra, that is always the case.

Comment: Continuity was used to say $\mu \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n = \lim_n \mu B_n = \lim_n \mu \bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_k = \lim_n \sum_{k=1}^{n}\mu A_k=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu A_k$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Agreed with you that there may exist a family such that the countable union will still belong to $\mathscr A$! But how the construction of $B_n$'s guarantees that $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \in \mathscr A$ ?

Comment: It doesn't. That is part of the hypothesis (which unfortunately isn't mentioned in the proof). Since $\mu$ is only defined on $\mathscr{A}$, we can only talk of countable additivity in a situation where we write an element of $\mathscr{A}$ as a countable disjoint union of elements of $\mathscr{A}$. It should better read "If $A_n$ is a sequence of pairwise disjoint sets in $\mathscr{A}$ _such that_ $\bigcup_{n = 0}^\infty A_n \in \mathscr{A}$ …".

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh! I was thinking that we have The Property and finite additivity of $\mu$ in the hypothesis and hence we have to construct sets in $\mathscr A$ (in this case $B_n$'s) such that they follow the Prerequisites for the property (i.e. $B_n \in \mathscr A$,$B_n \subset B_{n+1}$ and $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \in \mathscr A$) and then they directly give the result (i.e. $\mu(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n)= \lim_{n\to \infty} \mu(B_n)$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably good to clarify some definitions. If $\mathscr{A}$ is an algebra of sets, and $\mu \colon \mathscr{A} \to [0,+\infty]$ is a finitely additive set function, then we say that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive, if whenever $(A_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of pairwise disjoint sets in $\mathscr{A}$ such that $\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n \in \mathscr{A}$, then

$$\mu \biggl(\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} A_n\biggr) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \mu(A_n).$$

Since $\mu$ is only defined on $\mathscr{A}$, the condition only makes sense if the union is again a member of $\mathscr{A}$. In general, the union of a countable family of members of $\mathscr{A}$ need not belong to $\mathscr{A}$, and for every algebra that is not a $\sigma$-algebra at least one countable family whose union doesn't belong to the algebra exists.

Similarly, for the "continuity from below" property, we can only consider ascending sequences of members of $\mathscr{A}$ whose union is again a member of $\mathscr{A}$.

Then, to prove the equivalence of $\sigma$-additivity and continuity from below, note that we can write every union of an ascending sequence in $\mathscr{A}$ as the union of a sequence of pairwise disjoint members of $\mathscr{A}$: If $A_n \subset A_{n+1}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then since $\mathscr{A}$ is an algebra the sets $B_n = A_n \setminus A_{n-1}$ (where we set $A_{-1} = \varnothing$) belong to $\mathscr{A}$, and by construction they are pairwise disjoint, and

$$\bigcup_{n = 0}^\infty A_n = \bigcup_{n = 0}^\infty B_n.$$

And conversely, we can write every infinite union of members of $\mathscr{A}$ as the union of an ascending sequence in $\mathscr{A}$, if $A_n \in \mathscr{A}$ for all $n$, then $B_n = \bigcup\limits_{k = 0}^n A_k \in \mathscr{A}$ for all $n$, $B_n \subset B_{n+1}$, and

$$\bigcup_{n = 0}^\infty A_n = \bigcup_{n = 0}^\infty B_n.$$

So if $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive, and $A_n$ is an ascending sequence in $\mathscr{A}$ whose union again belongs to $\mathscr{A}$, then by $\sigma$-additivity we have

\begin{align}
\mu\biggl(\bigcup_{n = 0}^\infty A_n\biggr) &= \mu\biggl(\bigcup_{n = 0}^\infty (A_n \setminus A_{n-1})\biggr) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \mu(A_n \setminus A_{n-1})\\
&= \lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n = 0}^N \mu(A_n \setminus A_{n-1}) = \lim_{N\to \infty} \mu\biggl(\bigcup_{n = 0}^N (A_n \setminus A_{n-1})\biggr)\\
&= \lim_{N\to \infty} \mu\biggl(\bigcup_{n = 0}^N A_n\biggr) = \lim_{N\to \infty} \mu(A_N),
\end{align}

which is the continuity from below.

Conversely, if $(A_n)$ is a sequence of pairwise disjoint members of $\mathscr{A}$ whose union belongs to $\mathscr{A}$, then, with $B_n = \bigcup\limits_{k = 0}^n A_k$ we have

\begin{align}
\mu\biggl(\bigcup_{n = 0}^\infty A_n\biggr) &= \mu\biggl(\bigcup_{n = 0}^\infty B_n\biggr)\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(B_n) \tag{continuity from below}\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu\biggl(\bigcup_{k = 0}^n A_k\biggr)\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^n \mu(A_k)\tag{finite additivity}\\
&= \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \mu(A_k),
\end{align}

which is the $\sigma$-additivity.